# Is undeleting a potential duplicate acceptable?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, deleted-questions

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153433/if-wish-is-used-to-duplicate-a-spell-effect-is-the-spell-effect-treated-as-if-it) (deleted, viewable by 10k+ rep only) is deleted within minutes after a VTC as duplicate to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50258/can-you-use-wish-to-duplicate-a-spell-at-a-higher-level) is called.

[image]

It is indeed a duplicate to the suggested question.

Given that duplicates are actually valuable to us as a signpost to the referenced question, with different wording, we have established that [we should not delete a question after it is closed for being a duplicate.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/if-a-question-is-marked-as-a-duplicate-or-is-closed-should-i-delete-it)

But, if the question is *already deleted*, should we undelete the question to preserve the signpost, or let it be deleted?

Comment: Bear in mind, the question appeared, gathered two duplicate links and a duplicate close vote and was deleted in the space of approximately an hour.  I question its utility as a "good duplicate" if events transpired that quickly.

Comment: @Novak Though I'm unsure if this is strictly true as I cannot see the question: I am the one who mentioned both duplicate links and made the close vote all in the spam of a minute or so. The quickness of the events is mostly just me and then the asker chose to delete the question rather quickly

Comment: Are you asking about this specific question, or more generally? (If it's not about this specific question, you may want to remove the screenshot of the deleted question, as it ostensibly goes against their wishes.)

Comment: @Medix2 even so, that you were able to find two duplicate links in under an hour implies to me that finding the duplicates was quite easy, reducing the value of this new one.  The implication is that almost any effort would have found the duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't go out of my way to delete it as a third party; I wouldn't go out of my way to go against the wishes of the original poster and resurrect it as a third party, either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We should not actively delete duplicates.  But we also should err on the side of respecting a poster’s wishes.  I do not think it would be remotely appropriate to undelete a self-deleted question without a much more compelling reason than “well dupe signpost...”

If they had left it we should not delete it, but as they have deleted it we should not undelete it.  Interference requires a compelling reason.

Comment: Should we (EDIT: diamond mods) should leave a comment explaining the benefit of "signpost" duplicates, and possibly encourage them to undelete their question?

Comment: @V2Blast Can diamond mods leave comments on deleted posts? Those of us with only rep-based privileges sure can't.

Comment: @BESW: Ah, that's a good point. Diamond mods can indeed comment on deleted questions; I forgot regular users couldn't.

Comment: @V2Blast Then, I would suggest that mods not leave comments to that effect unless they want those suggestions to have the force of moderation.

Comment: You can if you want.  I wouldn’t as I would consider it a total waste of limited mod time.  Even mod instructional comments aren’t for just every situation.